# Why Vuex store instance is passed to Vue constructor parameters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    getters: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions: {}
})
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from './store'

// What is purpose of store parameter in Vue instance?
const app = new Vue({
    store
})

app.$mount('#app')
```

I have also seen similar syntax for Vue Router instance.

Comment: Because `Vue.use(Vuex)` installs a plugin, and the plugin makes use of the constructor parameter. Otherwise the store would not be accessible in your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax :

```
const app = new Vue({
    store
})
```

makes the store instance available for the child components like `this.$store`, if you don't do that the store will be not defined for your components or you have to import that store inside each one as :

```
import store from '../store'
//or 
import store from '../../store'
```

which is not good practice.